# Vue-CLI, TypeScript and monorepo: how to declare types outside of /src?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-cli, monorepo

How can I point the CLI to look for type declarations in a specific `@types` folder?

Any `*.d.ts` created in the `/src` folder is loaded and works perfectly, but if I move them anywhere outside of `/src` I get nothing.

My goal is to do this (as a monorepo):

```
/@types
/shared_stuff
/project_1
/project_2
```

I tried `compilerOptions.typeRoots` with no success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For future reference, I managed to achieve that with the following config inside tsconfig.json of each project:

`"include": [
    "../@types/*.d.ts"
]`

BUT, I had to leave the `shims-vue.d.ts` and `shims-jsx.d.ts` inside the /src of each project (because they import stuff included in node_modules of each projects).

Comment: hi @simon-peyou I had the same problem but I honestly don't think this is the cleanest way. Do you have any other solutions in mind? A sub-package with an index.d.ts containing all definitions should work too, shouldn't it?

Comment: @nkint I tried with no success. With and without hoisting. So I decided to go with this not so clean solution and wait for a better TypeScript integration in vuejs 3 (hopefully before the end of next year). And by then, monorepo will be more popular and more and more tools will adapt to them (as it happens every now and then since a few months). :)

Comment: so @simon-peyou ok : ) I've seen this one: https://github.com/Quramy/lerna-yarn-workspaces-example that uses `reference` a fresh new feature of TS 3 but it always relays on relative path so it lacks of the same "dirtyness", I'm using you solution too and waiting for better monorepo tooling ahahha